# How to check if the IP address that a socket is bound to is still one of the valid machine's addresses?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Once I call `socket()`; `bind()` (with a specific IP address, not `INADDR_ANY`); `listen()`, there seems to be no way of determining if the IP address is still a valid address of one of the system's interfaces.

What I looked into using:

- Checking error with `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)`;
- Using `epoll()`-ing on some `EPOLLERR`, `EPOLL{,RD}HUP` events;
- Hoping that `accept()` would return an error if the IP address is deleted when process is blocked on this syscall;

Non of those above seem to detect the IP address vanishing and/or change of interface state at all.

- Calling `bind()` in some timer callback to periodically check if the IP address may be bound, but this requires another socket has to be created it is not feasible.

I did not test these:

- Setting `SO_BINDTODEVICE` in the hope that this will change behavior of the facilities from the first triple in case interface goes down/IP address is removed.
- Calling some `ioctl()` like `SIOCSPGRP` or `FIOASYNC` since they promise to signal process about asynchronous events that hopefully include disappearance of an IP address.
- Using `netlink` to get routing table events, but this is very Linux-specific.

I'm hopping for a more portable way.

What I needing is some event similar to `RDMA_CM_EVENT_DEVICE_REMOVAL`, but with `AF_INET` sockets that would notify me when there is no bound interface with that IP address. Even this may be impossible to fulfill, because even `bind()` completes without error if the interface is down.

Comment: If you are `bind`ing to a certain address, and that address gets removed from the device and then re-added, you will still be able to receive packets (the `accept` will just hang there waiting in the meantime). That's probably why the kernel doesn't bother to signal the event through those interfaces.

Comment: To reliably detect when the IP is removed, you should explicitly ask the OS to notify you. For instance, using [`NotifyAddrChange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-notifyaddrchange) or [`NotifyIpInterfaceChange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netioapi/nf-netioapi-notifyipinterfacechange) on Windows, or [binding a `NETLINK_ROUTE` socket to `RTMGRP_IPV4_IFADDR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545139/65863) on Linux, etc

Comment: Literally ... an IP address always exists.   It is just a number.   What you are actually asking is something a lot more complicated.

Comment: @StephenC That is a valid point. I attempted to address it in the latest edit, alas, at the expense of brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to close a socket when the link goes down with BSD sockets.

This other questions shows how to listen for [network routing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27169191) mentioned by Remy.

A simpler way may be to check if the IP is currently bound before using the socket. This is a way to verify that `127.0.0.1` is still valid:

```
% cat checksocket.c && cc -o checksocket checksocket.c ; ./checksocket
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int main (void)
{
    struct ifaddrs *ifa, *i;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

    int ret = getifaddrs(&ifa);
    if (ret) {
        perror("getifaddrs:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = ifa; i != NULL; i = i->ifa_next) {
        ret = getnameinfo(i->ifa_addr, sizeof(*(i->ifa_addr)),
            host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
        char find[] = "127.0.0.1";
        int len = strlen(host);
        if (!ret && len && !strncmp(host, find, len)) {
            printf("Still valid: %s %s\n", i->ifa_name, ret ? "" : host);
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifa);

    return 0;
}
Still valid: lo0 127.0.0.1
```