# Detect IP-Address change on an interface

Tags: linux, networking, ip, systemd

I would like to trigger a service when a change of an ip address on a specific interface occurs. Is there a target for this or some other method I am not aware of to achieve this using systemd on Linux (Kernel 3.19)?

The service would be used to send a SIGNAL to a defined process. The Linux is running on an embedded system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use  [Systemd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/systemd) you might already use [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_DHCP) for managing your devices  instead of relying on 3rd party code.

You could use the structured journal output to get the last 2  `ADDRESS` field of the current *BOOD_ID*.(sadly, there is no notification mechanism for address changes in [systemd-networkd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd#Wired_adapter_using_DHCP)):

```
→ sudo journalctl -F ADDRESS -u systemd-networkd -n 2
192.168.178.29
```

So, if there is only one line output, there was no address change.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I can work with that, thanks!

Comment: Btw, how do you know the name of the ADDRESS field? I was not able to find it in the docs anywhere...

Comment: I used `sudo journalctl -u systemd-networkd -o json-pretty` to jeck the logging output of this service.

Answer (score 1):

There is an solution in other question of StackOverflow. Just here:
[Detecting a change of IP address in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738935/detecting-a-change-of-ip-address-in-linux)

I like this code, it's easy, you onli need a cron job with frecuency as you need (I made a little change):

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD_IP=`cat ip.txt`
NEW_IP=`/sbin/ifconfig  | awk -F "[: ]+'{ print $4}'`
if [ $NEW_IP != OLD_IP ]; then
    YOU_COMMAND <commands> 
    echo $NEW_IP > ip.txt
fi
exit 0
```