# Replacing old ip address in ubuntu server database with new ip address

Tags: mysql

I want to update my old IP address from MySQL with my new IP address. How can I do this?
Since the IP address on the server is renewed, I want to recognize a new IP address to the database.

Ubuntu-16
Nginx

Comment: I think the question you asked is not very clear, please  post some code or examples. :)

Comment: Question is confusing, but will try to help. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738935/detecting-a-change-of-ip-address-in-linux